# How can I add two arrays into a third?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So lets say I have a blank array:

```
$array = array();
```

And I have the following two arrays:

```
$array2 = array(
    'blah' => '1',
    'bleh' => '2',
)

$array3 = array(
    'halb' => '3',
    'helb' =< '4',
)
```

and I want it to say this:

```
$array = array(
    array2(
        'blah' => '1',
        'bleh' => '2',
    )
    array3(
        'halb' => '3',
        'helb' => '4',
    )
);
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: `$array = array($array2, $array3);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = array($array2, $array3);
```

If you needed keys:

```
$array = array('array2' => $array2, 'array3' => $array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your empty array can have new values appended using `[]` notation:

```
$array = array();

$array2 = array(
    'blah' => '1',
    'bleh' => '2',
);

$array3 = array(
    'halb' => '3',
    'helb' =< '4',
);

$array[] = $array2;
$array[] = $array3;
```